# Is WSH TCP server possible?

Tags: jscript, tcpserver

I want to write a script on windows using WSH jscript to be compiled by jsc.

I want the script to act as a very simple tcp server, listening to any port specified, and sending a text string upon receiving any request.

I have found some implementations which depend on a library that seems to only be available on windows machines with developer software installed. I need an implementation that can work on any windows machine (with .NET installed). I am happy to include a dll if there is one that can help to listen on tcp sockets.

Is there a suitable dll to act as a tcp server?

Is there a tcp server implementation in jscript that can be compiled with jsc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about [JScript.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript#JScript_.NET), which is separate from WSH.  Since JScript.NET is a CLR language, you can use any of the available .NET Framework classes.  Your best bet may be to find an example of a TCP server written in C# or VB.Net and then convert the code to JScript.NET.